# Is this the correct Laravel 5 model relationship?

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 database tables.

```
users
   id - integer
   username - string

post
   id - integer
   user_id - integer
   topic - string

comments
   id - integer
   user_id - integer
   post_id - integer
```

What I am doing in a view is I am looping through all the posts that a user has created by doing something like

```
Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

In each post, other users can comment on them. I would like to display a count on the post where it uniquely counts how many users have commented on that post. I thought that creating a hasManyThrough relationship would work here but I keep on getting a '0' count for users.

User Model:

```
class User extends Model {

public function post() 
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Post')
}

public function comment()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'user_id')
}

}
```

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model {

public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User')
}

public function comment()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')
}

// I thought this method below would return the users who had commented on the post

public function commenters()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Comment', 'user_id', 'username');
}

}
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment extends Model {

pubic function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User')
}

public function post()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Post')
}

}
```

So the end result should be something like this im guessing?

View:

```
<span>{{ $model->modelmethod->count() }}</span>
```

What are your guys opinions here? Is this the right approach? Or is there something different you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your first problem, *What I am doing in a view is I am looping through all the posts that a user has created by doing something like* you could use [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) - however, this will require you to access nesting element(s). This query retrieve a user and all of his post including commenters:

```
$user = User::with('post.commenters')->where('id', $userId)->firstOrFail();
```

This way you'll be able to access **an array of user's posts** with `$user->post`. Then to access it's commenters, you might specify array index (or use [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)).ie:

```
//this is array access, accessing first post
$user->post[0];
//this iterate all post using foreach
foreach($user->post as $posts){
  $post-> //do something with current post?
}
```

As for your second trouble, counting, it can be done in the database query - or in the view (i often do this in view, as it rather simple, readable and, less query).

```
//this prints all posts number of commenters - in blade
@foreach($user->post as $posts)
  @foreach($posts->commenter as $commenter)
    {{ count($commenter) }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**EDIT:**
looked like i miss to read your model carefully, it.. can't be done

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Comment', 'user_id', 'username');
```

it should be

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Comment', 'user_id', 'id');
```

as you actually use user_id instead of their username as foreign key in comments.

Comment: Hi tezla, i am looking to count the number of users who have commented. Not the number of comments.

Comment: ah mybad, you could fetch user through eager load - i'll edit my answer.

Comment: the key was toying with `::with(relationship)`, if you wish to retrieve post commenter, looking at your model relation - it can be done through that, however, that won't retrieve the actual comment.